# Joining different tables using different keys

Tags: sql, oracle, join

please help me to create a query for this: I have these 4 tables below:

**mast_comp**

```
id --- code

1 --- aa

2 ---bb

3 --- cc
```

**fin_calc**

```
fin_id --- val

11 --- 2

12 --- 4

33 --- 6
```

**fin**

```
fin_id --- code


11 --- aa

12 --- bb

33 --- cc
```

**mark_calc**

```
code --- calc


aa --- 10

bb --- 20

cc --- 30
```

Help me get to this desired output

**desired result**

```
id---fin_id---code---val---calc---calculated

1---  11---  aa---    2---  10---  12 
2---  12---  bb---    4---  20---  24
3---  33---  cc---    6---  30---  36
```

where calculated = val + calc

Sorry, I don't have starting queries to share because all attempts I tried failed... I want to start fresh.. Thanks. (please ignore hyphens I just used it to separate entries)

Comment: And what result you want with query from those tables???

Comment: Do you know you can nest more than one SELECT in one query?

Comment: PLease see desired result section... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select mc.id id, f.fin_id fin_id, f.code code, fc.val val, mcc.calc, fc.val + mcc.calc calculated
from mast_comp mc join fin f on mc.code = f.code
join fin_calc fc on f.fin_id = fc.fin_id
join mark_calc mcc on mc.code = mcc.code
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e654/6)